# What's the difference between @Named and @Qualifier in spring

Tags: java, spring

What's the difference between `@Named` and `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` in spring annotation configuration?
Which can be used to give a bean name to a bean (just like `'id'` in xml configuration)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@Named` is a Java standard (JSR 330), `@Qualifier` is used only for Spring; latest versions of Spring recognize both. I'd use `@Named` because `@Qualifier` is rather used to solve ambiguities where you have two or more beans of the same type.

Comment: There is a `@javax.inject.Qualifier`

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana you're right, there is a `javax.inject.Qualifier`, but the OP is refering to `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier`

Comment: `@Named` is a custom implementation of `@javax.inject.Qualifier`